# How to implement drag and drop in Angular2 with a firebase list / FirebaseListObservable

Tags: angular, firebase, drag-and-drop, angularfire2

I am trying to implement drag and drop into a list using angular2, firebase and dragula. I'm not tied to using dragula if there is a better module already built, but it seems simple. So far I get errors because dragula is trying to reorder the list as if it were a normal array.

```html
<ul class="list-group" [dragula]="statusList" [dragulaModel]='statusService.$statuses'>
<li *ngFor="let status of statusService.$statuses | async" class="list-group-item">
    
    <span class="handle">
        <img src="../../images/handle.png" />
    </span> 
   
    <span class="swatch" [style.backgroundColor]="status.color"></span>
    
    <span class="title">
        <inline-editor type="text" [(ngModel)]="status.title" (keyup.enter)="updateStatus(status, status.title)" (onSave)="updateStatus(status, status.title)" name="title" ngDefaultControl></inline-editor>
    </span>

    <a (click)="statusService.removeStatus(status)" class="remove-status">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </a>
                      
</li>
</ul>
```

I have implemented drag and drop with firebase and angular using the priority property. I am not seeing a clear way to do it in Angular 2, however.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observables are a perfect fit for creating drag-and-drop events.

Basically, this boils down to this:

1. You have to get a reference to the element that will be dragged
2. You have to create 3 different Observables:

   ```
   let down = Observable.fromEvent(draggedElement, 'mousedown');
   let move = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
   let up = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
   ```
3. You combine the Observables so that when a new `mousedown` on the `draggedElement` emits, you take all `mousemove` events, until `mouseup` is fired.

   ```
   let dragAndDrop = down.flatMap(() => move.takeUntil(up));
   ```
4. You subscribe to the dragAndDrop Observable and voila

   ```
   dragAndDrop.subscribe(position => console.log(position));
   ```

Comment: This is good information, but doesn't really get into an implementation with firebase lists which is what I am looking for.  Aside from firebase drag and drop is super simple in Angular2 and their are great pre-built components for it (like dragula).  It gets difficult for me when trying to update firebase list priorities.

Comment: You should copy the FirebaseList into a local array after subscribing. That way it is a simple list like any other and can be manipulated the same.

Comment: I added the implementation details below.

Answer (score 2):

So here are the implementation details:

1. I used Alexander's advice to subscribe to the firebase list and create a local array:

```js
this.statusService.$statuses.subscribe((statuses: [IStatus]) => {
  this.statuses = []; //reset local array used with dragula for drag and drop
  for (let status of statuses) {
    this.statuses.push(status);
  }
})
```

2. I used dragula's drop event to loop through and update the priority for each item in the array:

```js
dragulaService.drop.subscribe(() => {
  this.statuses.forEach((status, index) => {
    this.statusService.$statuses.update(status.$key, {
      priority: index
    });
  })
});
```

3. I ordered by priority in the query:

```js
this.$statuses = this.af.database.list(`/statuses/${session.$key}`, {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'priority'
  }
});
```

Finally I just use the local array as the dragula model and for *ngFor:

```html
<ul class="list-group" [dragula]="statusList" [dragulaModel]='statuses'>

  <li *ngFor="let status of statuses" class="list-group-item">
    
  etc...
```

Comment: Your answer literally just saved my life. Thank you.

Comment: Note sure but for [dragulaModel]='statuses' is not updating the model in class i.e. this.statuse. The index value is same as earlier :(