# How to implement ng2-dragula and firebase with sort

Tags: angular, firebase, drag-and-drop, firebase-realtime-database, ng2-dragula

I am trying to show names that have tables numbers and they are sorted by tableNumber.

My data looks like:

[image]

and my code is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dropAndDrag',
  template: `
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let item of (items|async)" [dragula]='"bag-one"' [dragulaModel]='(items|async)'></li>
</ul>

`
})
export class SortTableComponent {
  items: any;
  constructor(public service: SmartTablesService) {
    this.items=this.service.getData();
  }
}
```

the problem how can I group it by table number and show, this.items is array of objects, so also the template ng for should changed to get the name property like item.name .

Comment: seems possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049734/how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-in-angular2-with-a-firebase-list-firebaselistob